# Flattening multiple fields using Pivot Table in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, pivot-table

I'm trying to flatten a table, but I want to keep/relate certain fields tied to each other. For context, I ran a Generate Near Table to try to find the traffic volumes near intersections.

I am trying to keep the "Route_Name" field tied to the "Curr_Vol" field, while flattening it to the input field "IN_FID". (IN_FID is intersections, so we need to know what traffic volumes are near the intersection, and what route name is related to each traffic volume)

I've tried doing a pivot table, but I can't flatten the table to IN_FID completely while keeping the Route_Name and Curr_Vol fields.

Original data: 
[image]

After trying to run Pivot Table:

[image]

What data needs to look like in the end:
[image]

The result I want is a table where each row will have; The unique IN_FID value, the Route_Name & Curr_Vol values from every row in the original table, arranged as name1, vol1, name2, vol2, and so on.

I'm wondering if an ArcPy script would be the best solution?

However, I don't know how to write that complex of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the simple PyShp library, this solution should work...

```py
import shapefile
from collections import defaultdict

f = r'path/to/shapefile.shp'

feat_dict = defaultdict(list)

with shapefile.Reader(f) as shp:

    for rec in shp.iterRecords():
        # By using default dict, you can append to the existing dictionary list
        feat_dict[rec['IN_FID']].append((rec['CURR_VOL'],rec['ROUTE_NAME']))


for k, v in feat_dict.items():
    print(k, v)
```

You could also easily write that to a csv file if needed.

PyShp can be installed just by running "pip install pyshp" in your command line.